# unable to restore Table with pgAdmin3 backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pgadmin

By trying to restore table from a backup file I get response code 0, and yet my table is empty.

Default backup option in pgAdmin ends up with the statement

```
C:\main\PostgreSQL\9.5\pg95\bin\pg_dump.exe --host mylocalnetwork --port 5432 --username "efabis_admin" --no-password  --format custom --verbose --file "C:\Users\shelikhovskyy\Documents\test\efabis Cryo\backup\breeds_lang.backup" --table "efabis_admin.breeds_lang" "DAD_IS"

pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading transforms
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension tables
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "efabis_admin.breeds_lang"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "efabis_admin.breeds_lang"
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading policies
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = off
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "efabis_admin.breeds_lang"

Process returned exit code 0.
```

Ok, at this point I have 3MB file

First I create locally my "breeds_lang" table from SQL code in "SQL pane" in lower pgAdmin panel changing only owner to "postgres" default in local

and when I try to right click local table and go for default restore option I end up with

```
C:\main\PostgreSQL\9.5\pg95\bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "DAD_IS" --no-password  --data-only --table breeds_lang --schema postgres --verbose "C:\Users\shelikhovskyy\Documents\test\efabis Cryo\backup\breeds_lang.backup"

pg_restore: connecting to database for restore

Process returned exit code 0.
```

but my local table remains empty

Comment: try on your local db: `select count(1) from efabis_admin.breeds_lang`

Comment: relation "efabis_admin.breeds_lang" does not exist